# Can't figure out how to create a new empty project on Watson Studio after the redesign

Tags: visual-recognition, watson-studio

I'm taking the IBM Certification on Coursera and the instructions are to "create a project" and then select "visual recognition project" but after an apparent redesign, the 2nd option is no longer there. I read one previous post about this issue, but it did not solve my problem as the "create" button is grayed out and I'm not sure what to do to create this project.

Any tips would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are working on the "Introduction to Computer Vision with Watson and OpenCV" course. If so, please check the [discussion forum](https://www.coursera.org/learn/introduction-computer-vision-watson-opencv/discussions/weeks/1/threads/9QBlOre4EemqlxKS2b6iWg) where the original answer was posted.

Reposting the key information here: You will now find the option to create a visual recognition project in the menu on the left-hand side:

```
Services > Watson Services > Add Service > Visual Recognition
```

See [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ue9OD.png). According to a recent post, the course authors are working on updating the instructions.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, Watson interface for the project creation had been changed. If you still don't know how to solve the issue, you can follow the instructions from [this link](https://dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/docs/content/wsj/getting-started/projects.html) to create a new project on Watson Studio. Before this new design, we had to choose which type of project we will work accordingly the service we'll use. but now, we just add services to our project without declaring them in the beginning.

After creating the project, do the [following](https://dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/docs/content/wsj/analyze-data/visual-recognition-setting-up.html?audience=wdp):

1. From the Settings page of your project in Watson Studio, click Add
   service.
2. Choose the Watson services group.
3. Click the Visual Recognition service.
4. Click the New option to create a new instance of the Visual
   Recognition service, or click the Existing option to select an
   existing instance.

Let us know, if you face any other problem.